# Explanation for need of lifting when using ResourceT

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm trying to figure out how Conduits work and am getting caught up in the monads and transformers involved.

I boiled some sample code down to the following, which works:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile)
import Data.Conduit.List
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

downloadContent manager = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Nothing   -> return ()
    Just name -> do
      req <- lift $ parseUrl $ "http://" ++ name ++ ".com/"
      res <- lift $ http req manager
      lift $ responseBody res $$+- sinkFile $ name ++ ".html"
      downloadContent manager

main = do
  runResourceT $ do
    withManager $ \manager -> do
      sourceList ["google", "yahoo"] $$ downloadContent manager
```

What I don't understand is why I need to `lift` inside `downloadContent`. **Why do I need to use `lift` in the above code? What am I lifting *from* and *to*?** If I look at signatures:

```
parseUrl
  :: failure-0.2.0.1:Control.Failure.Failure HttpException m =>
     String -> m (Request m')

http
  :: (MonadResource m, MonadBaseControl IO m) =>
     Request m
     -> Manager
     -> m (Response
             (ResumableSource m Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString))

($$+-) :: Monad m => ResumableSource m a -> Sink a m b -> m b

downloadContent
  :: (MonadResource m, MonadBaseControl IO m,
      failure-0.2.0.1:Control.Failure.Failure HttpException m) =>
     Manager -> ConduitM [Char] o m ()

class (MonadThrow m, MonadUnsafeIO m, MonadIO m, Applicative m) => MonadResource m
```

This is not really helping me to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

`lift` takes an untransformed monadic action and wraps it so that you can run it inside a transformer:

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

In this case, the transformer is `ConduitM [Char] o`, which is defined in `Data.Conduit.Internal` as:

```
newtype ConduitM i o m r = ConduitM { unConduitM :: Pipe i i o () m r }
    deriving (..., MonadTrans, ...)
```

Which derives its `MonadTrans` instance using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` from the instance for `Pipe`:

```
instance MonadTrans (Pipe l i o u) where
    lift mr = PipeM (Done `liftM` mr)
```

Here’s a simpler example:

```
action :: ReaderT Int (State Int) ()
action = do           -- In the 'ReaderT Int (State Int)' monad.
  x <- ask            -- Ask for the (outer) 'Reader' environment.
  lift $ do           -- In the 'State Int' monad.
    modify (+x)       -- Modify the (inner) 'State' a couple of times.
    modify (+x)

main = print $ execState (runReaderT action 1) 1
```

We are in `ReaderT Int (State Int)` and our `modify` action is in `State Int`, so we need to `lift` the action in order to run it in the transformer. Note that, like in the above example, you ought to be able to merge your series of `lift`ed actions under one `lift`:

```
Just name -> do
  lift $ do
    req <- parseUrl $ "http://" ++ name ++ ".com/"
    res <- http req manager
    responseBody res $$+- sinkFile $ name ++ ".html"
  downloadContent manager
```